# Apache mod_rewrite, RewriteCond issue

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

At this question: [mod rewrite to remove file extension, add trailing slash, remove www and redirect to 404 if no file/directory is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032179/mod-rewrite-to-remove-file-extension-add-trailing-slash-remove-www-and-redirec)

In the solution I see this:
`RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php  -f`

Could you please someone explain what `$1` means here???

(*If the question title is not appropriate, please change it, thanks.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` is the result of the first captured regex previously specified in a `RewriteRule` statement.

See the official documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html