# Remove trailing .html rewriterule creates 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I have modified .htaccess to remove trailing .html from my pages. htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http://www.mydomain.co.uk} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+)\.html\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also added the following at the top of the .htaccess to set up a custom 404 page and stop indexing:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html
Options -Indexes
```

The rewrite rule works perfectly. So does the anti-indexing. However the 404 page gives me this error:

> Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@mydomain.co.uk and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

If I remove the rewriterule then the 404 page works fine. I don't know a lot about this kind of stuff and was wondering what to do to be able to get both aspects to work correctly? Can anyone help please?

(PS: I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032179/mod-rewrite-to-remove-file-extension-add-trailing-slash-remove-www-and-redirec) and think it might apply to me - but didn't understand it at all.)

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to let you know I found a solution for this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.html

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/\ ]+/)*[^.\ ]+\.htm\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.htm$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$ /$1.html [L]
```

Works great!